# During locked screen: Notificaton 'Rights requested'. Google Account manager then crashes

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, notifications, 4.3-jelly-bean, google-account, crashes

Since a few days ago, my device has started showing an exclamation mark in the status bar when the lock screen is active. Today, this happened several times.

In the notification area there is a message that says:

> Rights requested for account myAccountName@gmail.com

This is the phone's main account.

If I click on the message, Google account manager seemingly starts - and immediately shows a message indicating it has stopped. I assume this means that it crashed.

I didn't do anything myself that created the notification the notification since lock screen was enabled.

Is this is just odd programming, Or should I investigate further? May a virus be active?

System: Galaxy S3, Android 4.3 and [SRT AppGuard](http://www.srt-appguard.com) installed.

**UPDATE 20140720**

I long-pressed the notification to get **App details**. Reports the details of **Google Account Manager**.

As said in my comment, I'd expect a **crash in a user-installed application**.

**UPDATE 20140728**

Recently, several time **App details** reported AppGuard as the problem app.

Comment: Have you followed up to check which app is behind it (i.e. causing the notification, by long-pressing it and follow up to the app info)? Could it be an app you manipulated with SRT? A missing permission (one you revoked using SRT) could possibly cause a crash, if the resulting exception is not handled.

Comment: @Izzy Thank you! That's what I guess too. I wonder, why Google account manager crashes, not the application itself. No, I didn't press the notification long. I'll give it a try.

Comment: That's what puzzled me, too (and why I didn't make it an answer straight ahead). I personally wouldn't use SRT at all for several reasons, but almost all alternatives require root (not an option for everybody)… Let's see what the notification reports as its source.

Comment: @lzzy Reports Google Account Manager, no user-installed application.

Comment: Sorry, out of ideas then. Except for removing all SRT stuff from the device, and replace SRT by something else (guess your question is already on SR for that ;) and see whether that improves the situation.